# TCL use a variable to generate a varaible and use a variable for file open/close

Tags: tcl

As an easy example I just want to loop thorugh opening/closing files and use a variable to create another variable. In PERL this is pretty easy but I cnat figure it out in TCL

```
set gsrs ""
lappend gsrs "sir"
lappend gsrs "dir"

foreach gsr $gsrs {
  set file "sdrv/icc/instance_toggle_overwrite.$gsr.txt"
  puts "*** I : Generating $file"

  set tempGSR gsr
  puts "$$tempGSR" # would like output to be value of $gsr
  set $gsr [open $file "w"] # normally you would not use a variable here for filename setting
  close $$gsr
}
```

Comment: Found someone who doesn't `use strict;` like they should in perl.

Answer (score 2):

Double-dereferencing is usually not recommended, as it leads to complex code that is quite hard to maintain. However, if you insist on doing it then use `set` with *one* argument to do it:

```
puts [set $tempGSR]
```

Usually, thinking about using this sort of thing is a sign that either `upvar` (possibly `upvar 0`) or an array should be used instead.

Comment: you are probably correct on that, Just used to how easy this is to do in PERL :)